# J2ME WMA send SMS for device without MIDlet installed

Tags: java-me, sms, wma, inbox

I'm using the WMADemo from the J2ME samples to send and receive SMS.

If I send one SMS from the SMSSend MIDlet for one device that doesn't have SMSReceive MIDlet installed the message goes to the inbox.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: *deleted, misunderstood*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the message to be received by the MIDlet if it's present, and to be discarded if it's not installed, is that right?

There's nothing you can do about that, it's down to the individual handset.  Some handsets (e.g. Nokia S40) will silently discard an SMS sent to a port number if there is no MIDlet listening for the message, whereas others will just display it as if it were a regular SMS.